# State Machine Implementations

Tags: design-patterns, state-machine

I am trying to build a board game ... And looks like it has to be implemented using a state machine..

I know of the [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) from GoF, but I am sure there must be other ways to implement state machine. Please let me know.. if you know of any articles or books that contains details about different implementation (trade off of each of them), please direct me.. thanks

Comment: Are you sure a state machine is appropriate for a board game? Seems strange to me.

Comment: Do you want to implement a game server, or a computer player for the game? In the first case a state machine makes sense, in the second it makes less sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/).

Answer (score 2):

We've used Harel's statecharts (similar/equivalent to state machines but somewhat easier to think about), there's a good book called [Practical Statecharts in C/C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578201101).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple FSM implementation:

```
public delegate void ProcessEvent<TEvent>(TEvent ev);

public abstract class StateMachine<TEvent>
{
    private ProcessEvent<TEvent> state;

    protected ProcessEvent<TEvent> State
    {
        get { return this.state; }
        set { this.state = value; }
    }

    public void ProcessEvent(TEvent ev)
    {
        this.state(ev);
    }
}
```

You would use it as follows:

```
public class MyFsm : StateMachine<byte>
{
    public MyFsm()
    {
        this.State = this.Started;
    }

    private void Started(byte ev)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ev);

        if (ev == 255)
        {
            this.State = this.Stopped;
        }
    }

    private void Stopped(byte ev) { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyFsm fsm = new MyFsm();
        fsm.ProcessEvent((byte) 0);
        fsm.ProcessEvent((byte) 255);
        fsm.ProcessEvent((byte) 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that's C#? it would help to clarify which language (doesn't quite look like Java or C++)

Answer (score 0):

Finite State Machines provide the best platform to implement games which are all events driven.

Since your goal is to build the state machine you can use an existing framework and than all you need is to add your events extractors and actions.

One example framework can be seen at:

http://www.StateSoft.org

Comment: Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is required that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Looks like statesoft.org domain is parked now?